# Sql Server Fill Factor - Restart sql server services

Tags: sql-server, fill-factor

I changed the Fill Factor option from 1 to 75.

When I run a query that displays the fill Factor I am seeing 75

But I read online that I have to stop and start the sql Server services inorder for this change to be effective. Is that True?

http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/fill-factor-truth

> You must stop and restart the SQL Server service for the change to take effect. The new fill factor will be in effect when you see it in the run-value column

Comment: Are you sure you queried the run value and not config value? What query did you use to check.

Comment: In addition to restarting, please also note that Fill Factor will not go back and change your old data to the new fill factor, so your indexes will remain how they are currently.  Only new data coming in get's that fill factor.  If you reindex or somewhere it fills up more/less it won't go back and change it back to that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I read online that I have to stop and start the sql Server services inorder for this change to be effective. Is that True?

Yes, you have to stop and restart sql server services.

> fill factor (%)

This has <kbd>is_dynamic = 0</kbd> in the `master.sys.configurations`.  This means that when you run `sp_configure 'fill factor (%)', 75`, the VALUE will be set to `75`, but it wont take affect until you restart sql server.

You should check <kbd>value in use</kbd> for `master.sys.configurations` or <kbd>run_value</kbd> of the `sp_configure` output.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is clearly stated here which options require a restart: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631.aspx